How to fix 30+ GB in Preboot
I'm running out of disk space, and I discovered that 30+GB is in /System/Volumes/Preboot. I'm not sure how I can safely free this space up.
Any help would be much appreciated!
/System/Volumes/Preboot
   21.0 GiB [#############################] /46B639CF-949D-4C5E-8696-318F92825F25                                                                                                                            
    9.2 GiB [############                 ] /Cryptexes                                                                                                                                                       
   34.5 MiB [                             ] /staging                                                                                                                                                         
    0.0   B [                             ] /00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000                                                                                                                            
    0.0   B [                             ] /com.apple.security.cryptexd                                                                                                                                     
    0.0   B [                             ]  .TemporaryItems  

                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                        

/System/Volumes/Preboot/46B639CF-949D-4C5E-8696-318F92825F25
   19.4 GiB [#############################] /cryptex1                                                                                                                                                        
  740.9 MiB [#                            ] /restore                                                                                                                                                         
  739.4 MiB [#                            ] /restore-staged                                                                                                                                                  
  131.7 MiB [                             ] /boot                                                                                                                                                            
   11.5 MiB [                             ] /PreLoginData                                                                                                                                                    
   10.5 MiB [                             ] /usr                                                                                                                                                             
    2.5 MiB [                             ] /System                                                                                                                                                          
    2.2 MiB [                             ] /var                                                                                                                                                             
   28.0 KiB [                             ] /Library                                                                                                                                                         
    0.0   B [                             ] /etc 

                                                                                                                                                        
                   

/System/Volumes/Preboot/46B639CF-949D-4C5E-8696-318F92825F25/cryptex1
9.7 GiB [#############################] /proposed                                                                                                                                                        
9.7 GiB [############################ ] /current 

/System/Volumes/Preboot/46B639CF-949D-4C5E-8696-318F92825F25/cryptex1/proposed
    4.8 GiB [#############################]  os.dmg                                                                                                                                                          
    4.8 GiB [#############################]  os.clone.dmg                                                                                                                                                    
   22.0 MiB [                             ]  app.dmg                                                                                                                                                         
    2.7 MiB [                             ]  BuildManifest.plist                                                                                                                                             
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  os.dmg.trustcache                                                                                                                                               
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j313ap.3786811E3401E.im4m                                                                                                                              
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.vma2macosap.im4m                                                                                                                                       
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j615ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j613ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j504ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j493ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j473ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j457ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j456ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j434ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j433ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j415ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j413ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j313ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j293ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j274ap.im4m                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j516sap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j516map.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j516cap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j514sap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j514map.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j514cap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j475dap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j475cap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j474sap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j416sap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j416cap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j414sap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j414cap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j375dap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j375cap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j316sap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j316cap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j314sap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j314cap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  apticket.j180dap.im4m                                                                                                                                           
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  app.dmg.trustcache                                                                                                                                              
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  SystemVersion.plist                                                                                                                                             
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  RestoreVersion.plist                                                                                                                                            
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  os.dmg.root_hash                                                                                                                                                
    4.0 KiB [                             ]  app.dmg.root_hash 

                                 


Mine is not much smaller, but I don't have the proposed folder which seems to account for the difference. You could try removing that, at your own risk. I suggest you rename it first and then reboot, to make sure you don't break anything.

Which specific (version number) version of macOS are you running? Did you try to update it recently?

@nohillside My macOS is macOS 14.4.1 (23E224) Sonoma. I didn't try to update it, but I did see that Software Update automatically downloaded some update (Sequoia 15.1 and Sonoma 14.7.1)(I've since disabled automatic downloading of updates). My best guess right now is that the Preboot stuff are updates (if so, of which I have no intention to install, I hate breaking my workflows).

Install 14.7.1 then at least, this shouldn’t break any workflows (but brings security fixes). It might also cleanup stuff in preboot.

I've installed 14.7.1 and now Preboot is only 20GB. the /proposed directory inside /cryptex1 is gone. Now I'm just a little tempted to delete the whole Preboot... (I never asked for downloading 10s of GBs of updates...)

I would use recovery mode to re-install the OS. It will keep all your files intact as you probably know. Make up backup first if it feels too risky. This should return the preboot volume to it's normal state....ie. MB's not GB's !
